# Android OpenGLES remaining() < size < needed

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

At first I am not used to develop apps. Until now I only used LWJGL for computer games, so don't be too strict to me :)

I tried to implement a VAO class, which cares about all this VAO stuff (loading VAO's, VBO's, binding indices buffers etc.)

The problematic code snippet is the one in the bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices) function.

*Vao.java:*

```
private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices){
    int vboID =genBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    IntBuffer buffer = Tools.makeIntBuffer(indices);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.length*4, buffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Additional Code:

```
private int genBuffers(){
    int[] ids = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, ids, 0);
    return ids[0];
}
```

*Tools.java:*

```
 public static IntBuffer makeIntBuffer(int[] arr){
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length *4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
    ib.put(arr);
    ib.position(0);
    ib.flip();
    return ib;
}
```

The Main activity class calls a sub class of GLSurfaceView, which creates the MasterRenderer which implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer and calls the render methods of the seperate renderers in onDrawFrame();

I get the following error:

*E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)*

*D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM*

*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main*

...

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: remaining() < size < needed*

At the line "GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.length*4, buffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);"

And now the magic question: what did I do wrong? :D

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much it works now!